# How Can I copy a large amount of data?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, file-transfer

i have 250gb external harddisk... I would like copy all of the data from that external harddisk to my laptop but i can't seem to copy so many files.  Whenever I attempt to copy and paste to my laptop harddisk 500GB I get a

> Not Responding Error

How can I copy a large amount of files from one hard drive to another?

Comment: we need more details...

Comment: nice job! @KronoS.

Answer (score 1):

Connect both host ends of the cable to different USB ports so that the drive gets plenty of power, and use a tool with built-in reliability such as rsync to actually perform the copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are copying from between drives on the the same system or to a file share try teracopy -- http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows 7, Vista, or XP, Microsoft has a fairly full-featured free utility called [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52&displaylang=en) which could probably do the job.

It's a "smart" file copier in that only copies files which don't exist on the destination or are older than the versions on the source, so if the transfer is ever interrupted for some reason, it can be restarted and will resume where it left off.

There are a number of other, similar file "syncing" programs available, both free and not, for Windows as well as most other Operating Systems. One well-know free ones for *nix system's is called [`rsync`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).